# How can I define an environment variable in Mac OS X 10.9?

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, terminal, environment-variables

I need to define environment variables for AWS S3.

Specifically,

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

how can I permanently define these environment variables via the terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="value"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="value"
```

Comment: If youw ant these settings for all terminal sessions, yes.